# hibernate session close

Tags: hibernate, session, caching, struts2, interceptor

I just followed a simple hibernate struts tutorial and succesfully made db calls through hibernate. However I don't see the code closing the hibernate connection anywhere.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

is used to get the session per request. Should I close this session when the user logs out? or after each request of is this something taken care of by the framework?

a second related question is, In what kind of use case would I use a hibernate session interceptor?

and a third question(sorry it just popped in my mind) what the best option for caching with hibernate/struts2?

Comment: Too many questions in a single one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the first question, the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-workingpersistence) says:

> A org.hibernate.Session begins when the first call to
>   getCurrentSession() is made for the current thread. It is then bound
>   by Hibernate to the current thread. When the transaction ends, either
>   through commit or rollback, Hibernate automatically unbinds the
>   org.hibernate.Session from the thread and closes it for you.

Regarding your second question, [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-interceptors) says:

> The Interceptor interface provides callbacks from the session to the
>   application, allowing the application to inspect and/or manipulate
>   properties of a persistent object before it is saved, updated, deleted
>   or loaded. One possible use for this is to track auditing information.
>   For example, the following Interceptor automatically sets the
>   createTimestamp when an Auditable is created and updates the
>   lastUpdateTimestamp property when an Auditable is updated.

Regarding the third question, Struts2 is a presentation framework. It has nothing to do with persistence and thus caching of the persistent entities. [The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-cache) talks in details about the second-level cache.

As you see, the documentation has a whole lot of interesting information. I would advise reading it.

Answer (score 2):

Need more information to answer your question like how you are using hibernate and we are really clueless which tutorial your are following :)regarding your questions

1. Hibernate session represent a unit of work and it always good practice to close session.I don't see a relation of hibernate session with the user login/logout process.Please do not mix the concept of web-session with hibernate session as both are quite different.
2. For caching at hibernate level you can use ehcache as second level cache and hibernate  provide out of the box first level cache for you, for Struts2 side i will recommend EHCache, a overall good and flexible caching solution.

My suggestion is if you are learning about Strust2 and Hibernate so its better to skip the caching part and concentrate on the core areas