# Difference between SessionFactory.openSession() & SessionFactory.getCurrentTransaction().commit()

Tags: java, hibernate

what would happen if I close the session with `Session.getCurrentTransaction().commit()` or close the session with `session.close()` at the end of my method?

```
public static void deleteYear(Years year)
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(year);
            // what is the best way to close session
    session.getTransaction().commit();
            //or : session.close(); ???
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASAIK, these two are entirely different operations.

`sessionFactory.openSession()`: It opens a [session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html)

`session.beginTransaction()`: It begins a [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms190612%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), a transaction is a atomic unit of work which should succeed or fail entirely.

`session.getTransaction().commit()`: It commit the transaction, means all the things happened between beginTransaction and this call will get persisted to database. If you doesn't commit a transaction then all the changes happened in the transaction will be lost. Commiting a transaction deosn't close the session

`session.close()`: closes the session and releases the acquired resources.

That means you need to call both `commit()` and `session.close()`.

```
public static void deleteYear(Years year)
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(year);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do session transactions

```
Session sess=getSession();
Transcration tx=sess.beginTranscration();
//do something with session
sess.save(obj);
tx.commit();
sess.close;
```

And i am recommending [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351390/hibernate-session-close) .

Answer (score 0):

These are two different things totally.

`COMMIT` makes the changes which have taken place within the `transaction` so far.
`CLOSE` closes the session, and you no longer have access to that session.

So you can have both together.

**A note to remember**: Closing a session is not necessary; however, a session should be `DISCONNECT`ed at the end.